# MVC Partial View throwing error on dropdownfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view I want to display as a search interface. Every time it tells me I get the error

> There is no ViewData item of type IEnumerable that has the key resource_type_id.

I have tried so many things to make this work but nothing helps.

This is my view calls the partialview

```
@model IEnumerable<NewSAMACentral2._0.ViewModel.MemberResourcesViewModel.MemberResource>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Resource To Folder";
}
<h2>Add Resource To Folder</h2>
<div>
    @{Html.Partial("SearchResource", new NewSAMACentral2._0.ViewModel.MemberResourcesViewModel.ResourceSearch());}
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("InsertAttendee", "Meetings", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    if (Model.Any())
    {
    }
}
```

This is my partialview

```
@model NewSAMACentral2._0.ViewModel.MemberResourcesViewModel.ResourceSearch
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendee", "Meetings", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AddAttendee", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="keyword">Keyword(s): </label>@Html.TextBox("keyword", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.resource_type_id)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.resource_type_id, Model.resource_type, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author">Author(s): </label>@Html.TextBox("author", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

This is the controller that never seems to get called...

```
public PartialViewResult SearchResource()
{
    var results = new MemberResourcesViewModel.ResourceSearch();
    results.resource_type = db.Resource_Types.Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = s.name,
        Value = s.id.ToString()
    }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Text);
    return PartialView(results);
}
```

This is the ViewModel

```
namespace NewSAMACentral2._0.ViewModel
{
    public class MemberResourcesViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MemberResource> MemberResourceResult;
        public MemberResource memberResource;

        public class MemberResource
        {
            public ResourceSearch resource_search { get; set; }
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Resource Title")]
            public string title { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> resource_type { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Resource Type")]
            public string resource_type_id { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Keyword")]
            public string keyword { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Author")]
            public string author { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Subject Type")]
            public string subject_type { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Industry")]
            public string industry { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Description")]
            public string description { get; set; }
        }

        public class ResourceSearch
        {
            [DisplayName("Author")]
            public string author { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> resource_type { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Resource Type")]
            public string resource_type_id { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Keyword")]
            public string keyword { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it from `DropDownListFor( model => Model.resource_type_id )` to `DropDownListFor( m => m.resource_type_id )`. and apply the same change to your other HTML helpers.

Answer (score 0):

On your main View Action (not partial view action result):

```
var types = db.Resource_Types.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
SelectList typeList = new SelectList(types, "ID", "Name");
ViewBag.Types = typelist;
```

All that was done there was pull your objects from the DataBase. Then we turned that into a Select list with 'ID' as the value field and 'Name' as the text field. Then we put that select list in a viewbag to be used by our view.

Next In your partial view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.resource_type_id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Types, "value", "text"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The only difference in this HTML is its pulling values from the select list so you never have to worry about it even hitting the partial view controller. I also changed the capital 'M' in model to a lowercase because not needed

Remember to put the code for the ViewBag in your main actionresult, not the partial view action result.

As Stephen commented below all you really need is :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.resource_type_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Types, "-Select-", ...)
```

Comment: It just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.resource_type_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Types, "-Select-", ...)` The `ViewBag.Types` property is already a `SelectList`. Its pointless (and unnecessary extra overhead) to create a new `SelectList` from it again.

Comment: If user wanted a default selected value would go my way, but you're right, it works either way

Comment: If you want a 'default value` you assign the value to the property in the controller. Your code is pointless and just creates a duplicate `SelectList` from the existing `SelectList`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be carefull with capital letters and put model not Model:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.resource_type_id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.resource_type_id, model.resource_type, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because the value of `Model.resource_type` is null when used inside the `DropDownListFor()` method.

In your main view you use `Html.Partial()` to render a partial view named `SearchResource.cshtml`, passing it a new instance of your class `ResourceSearch`. But `ResourceSearch` does not have a default constructor which initializes the `resource_type` property so its `null`, hence the exception.

Your naming conventions and use of nested models make it difficult to understand, and you have not shown the GET method for the main view, but I suspect you are wanting to actually call the `SearchResource()` method on your controller which will return the partial view of the form. In which case you need to use

```
@{Html.RenderAction("SearchResource")}
```

which will call the method and return its partial. Since that method initializes a new instance of `ResourceSearch` and populates its `resource_type` property, it will no longer be `null`

Note you should also consider applying the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to the method so it cant be called by the user entering the url in the address bar.